# RTC: Search for Items which Mention a Specific User

Tags: rtc

I'm looking for a query or a way to define one of my own to search for all work items which mention a specific user.  How can I do this?

Comment: i am looking for something similar, as there is a property in queries for "mentions" but it just filters for "there is a mention of a person"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "mention".

You could make a simple query on the attribute "Full Text", for a string representing your user.

Or you could make a query on the attributes "Comments", which list all the members of a project area.

Comment: Fulltext for @Username will ignore the @ unfortunately (4.0.6)

Comment: @x29a I'll have to check if that is still the case with 5.x

Comment: Unfortunately, on 5.0.1, the "mentions" condition still has no value to be set. Fulltext for "@username" still escapes the @ so the result is a fulltext search for "username".